# Calculating speed using public GPS data

Tags: python, gps, web-scraping

I'm scraping a web API that displays the latitude and longitude of a bus.

The web-service doesn't seems to have a fixed update time for the GPS position, it can take from 1 second to up to 30 seconds.

When the update takes long I get a reasonable speeds (10km/h~80km/h), but when the update happens in less than 10 seconds, I get unreal speeds, up to 1000 km/h.

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """Calculate the distance between two points"""
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

def get_speed(new_lat, new_lng, cur_time):
    old_lat, old_lng, old_time = buses[bus_prefix]
    if (new_lat, new_lng) != (old_lat, old_lng):
        distance = haversine(old_lng, old_lat, new_lng, new_lat)
        speed = distance / (cur_time - old_time) * 3600
        _speed = "%.1f km/h" % speed
        updated_time = "%02d:%02d"%(divmod(cur_time-old_time, 60))
        return _speed, updated_time

    return None, None

url = 'http://api.plataforma.cittati.com.br/m3p/js/vehicles/service/22233'

buses = {}

with requests.session() as s:
    while True:
        response = s.get(url)
        t = time.time()
        content = json.loads(response.content)
        for bus in content:
            bus_prefix = bus['prefix']
            latitude = bus['lat']
            longitude = bus['lng']
            if bus_prefix in buses:
                speed, update_time = get_speed(latitude, longitude, t)
                if speed and update_time:
                    print "Bus {bus_prefix} is traveling at {speed}\t" \
                    "Last update in: {update_time}".format(**locals())
            buses[bus_prefix] = latitude, longitude, t
        time.sleep(1)
```

Maybe I'm doing some math wrong, or the buses in my city are racing, but I double checked everything, including the racing!

Here's a debug I did to try to figure out what's going on:

```
old_lat = -32.0916777778
new_lat = -32.0937277778

new_lng = -52.1608333333
old_lng = -52.1598611111

distance = 0.245660526035 in kms

old_time = 1436580324.66 in epoch seconds
cur_time =  1436580325.94 in epoch seconds

delta time = 1.28700017929 in seconds
speed = 687.162214861 in km/h

Bus 1145 is traveling at 687.2 km/h Last update in: 00:01
```

Can anyone spot any mistake? Or is this the right approach? Is Haversine the right tool for this job?

Comment: There will be all sorts of latencies in the reporting system which account for the variable speeds you're seeing. Unless you can get a timestamp for the GPS report this is going to be fraught with inaccuracies. You might try a rolling average over several minutes to see if that helps.

Comment: I see this field in your posted `url` : `"ts":1436582318000` .. isn't it this a time stamp for `lat` and `long` values?...if that's the case, you should read it as well and use it for your computation, no?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was wondering what this number was, I assumed it was some tracking info, but it's milisecond timestamp. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your posted `url`, I got the follwoing output:

`[{"plate":"IUZ4600","prefix":"1310","ts":1436583122000,"lat":-32.061505555555556,"lng":-52.147172222222224,"bearing":37},{"plate":"ISO8600","prefix":"1145","ts":1436583099000,"lat":-32.15838333333333,"lng":-52.19098888888889,"bearing":309}]`

This is a list of dictionaries, where I assume each dictionary is referring to one bus,

In Each dictionary, there is a `key` called `ts`, it should be the time stamp for each updated `lat` and `long`, it's corresponding `value` should be used into your calculations for the `speed` to give you more accurate results:

`t = bus["ts"]`

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is that since gps is not super precise, if measurement 1 and measurement 2 are both off by 100m in opposite directions, that is an additional 200m of distance. The longer the time the less that discrepancy affects the results. I would say the best solution is to only take updates that are more that 15 seconds or so, and therefore minimize the error.